# jQuery find with parameter

Tags: jquery

I'm writing this:

```
var SomeClass = "MyClass";
$('#SomeID').find(SomeClass).each(function () { .... });
```

For some reason, when I get into the .each loop, it's not returning any elements.

I thought `.find` would work with a string as a parameter but it's not. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot to add '.' in class. modified code:-

```
var SomeClass = ".MyClass";
$('#SomeID').find(SomeClass).each(function () { .... });
```

Comment: Or, of course, `.find('.' + SomeClass)` (but that's perhaps just being silly...).

Answer (score 1):

just add the class to the selector:

```
var SomeClass = "MyClass";
$('#SomeID.'+SomeClass+'').each(function () { .... });
```